# How can I load PHP GET values using jquery .load()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to load data from another page. The data that I am trying to load is simple PHP `$_GET` value that was passed through a URL

The `$_GET` value should be loaded  only when the following link has been clicked on.

The data only loads when I use the following href link :

```
<a id="pizza" href="#">Pizza</a>
```

However when I use this href tag

```
<a id="pizza" href="menu.php?test_val=1">Pizza</a> <!-- The link is on the same as the menu.php page >
```

The content does not get loaded. I figured out that it doesn't get loaded because I set the content to display only when the link gets clicked on like so...

```
<script>
$("#pizza").on("click", function(){
    $("#item_description").load("item-details.php");
})
</script>
```

The problem is when I click on the link it starts a new XHTTP request and doesn't reach the

```
$("#item_description").load("item-details.php");
```

Because nothing is being clicked on when there is new XHTTP request.

The item-details page just echo's out the value that was sent

```
<?php
  echo $_GET['test_val']; 
?>
```

Can anyone please help me come up with a solution??

Thanks!!

Comment: Have you tried `return false;` within the `.on(...)`?

Comment: Hey Dave. I am not sure what does returning false do..

Comment: When you used `#` as the href, you said it works. If you want to stop the page from navigating away, you can return false within your onClick (jQuery -> `.on(...)`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
<a id="pizza" href="#">Pizza</a>
```

to keep your link format and you can use

```
$("#item_description").load("item-details.php?myvar=1&mysecondvar=2");
```

to pass your value to your PHP script

you can  read GET value by parsing :

```
window.location.href
```

if needed

Comment: Thank a lot BeepMaster that worked!!
Where would i need to parse window.location.href?

Comment: Read this link for example :

http://www.sitepoint.com/url-parameters-jquery/


You can also use PHP to set a value to a javascript var  example : <?php echo "<script>var myVar=".$_GET['myvar']."</script>"?> 

This line will generate : <script>varMyVar=2</script> ... if 2 is set ...